# How do I delete the Device policy work app when uninstall and force quit are disabled?

Tags: android, adb, admin, samsung-galaxy, device-policy-manager

I got given a phone by a friend which he couldn’t use because of an it administrator lock. The app causing this is called Device policy(com.Google.apps.android.work.clouddbc). The options to uninstall or force quit are greyed out. I have tried everything to do with uninstalling using ADB but nothing works, I also tried unlocking bootloader but I get an error message saying work accounts can’t be set up due to a custom is being installed. What do I do?

Comment: Off-topic on this site. See: [Remove work profile from personal device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/239466/3573) and [related posts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=work+profile)

Comment: Should be on android.stackexchange.com.  But I'd try a factory reset.  May even need to flash a new firmware or go into device recovery mode to do it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.